# Call a functionfrom command line with arguments - Python (multiple function choices)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I'm using Python 3.6, I have a file called file.py, with have this two functions:

```
def country(countryName):
    print(countryName)

def capital(capitalName):
    print(capitalName)
```

I need to call any of these two methods from Command Line, but sincerely I don't know how to do that, also with arguments in this way.

```
python file.py <method> <argument>
```

Does someone knows how to do that?

Greetings!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use command line arguments in a program you can use sys.argv. [Read more](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm)

```
import sys

def country(countryName):
    print(countryName)

def capital(capitalName):
    print(capitalName)

method_name = sys.argv[1]
parameter_name = sys.argv[2]

getattr(sys.modules[__name__], method_name)(parameter_name)
```

To run the program:

```
python file.py capital delhi
```

output:

```
delhi
```

Your input parameter method_name is a string so can't be called directly. Hence we need to fetch the method handle using `getattr`.

Command `sys.modules[__name__]` fetches the current module. which is file.py module. Then we use `getattr` to fetch the method we want to call and call it. we pass the parameter to the method as `(parameter_name)'

Comment: Thank you so much Singh! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could have a module that inspects your file.py, call it executor.py, and adjust your methods in file.py to handle argument lists

executor.py:

```
import file
import sys    

method = file.__dict__.get(sys.argv[0])
method(sys.argv[1:-1])
```